# for loop return , I am can't get values. Only returns last value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use for loop to set the array value, but I just get the last input value of the data value. in other words, console.log(data) only output the last value.

export default class App extends React.Component {
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

```
 state={
    form:{
      name:'',
      country:'',
      age:''
    }
 }
onButton=()=>{
   const data = {};
    for(let element in this.state.form){
        data[element] = this.state.form[element]
    }
   console.log(data)
 }
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{marginTop:100,width:'100%'}}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      value={this.state.form.name}
      onChangeText={(name)=>this.setState({form:{name}})}
     />
      <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      value={this.state.form.country}
      onChangeText={(country)=>this.setState({form:{country}})}

     />
      <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      value={this.state.form.age}
      oonChangeText={(age)=>this.setState({form:{age}})}

     />
     </View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.onButton()} style={{borderColor:'green',borderWidth:1,padding:10,marginTop:50}}>
          <Text>GONDER</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
 );
```

}
}

Comment: I dont understand the question, can you explain breifly what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: That _"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."_ is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

the element return is an object, and when copy value, you should use {...object} not array way. you can like this:

```
onButton=()=>{
   const data = {};
    data = {...this.state.form}
   console.log(data)
 }
```